# Double confirmation box in Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I have a view in Symfony that contains a form. Before submitting the form I have a confirmation box in jQuery. After submitting the form, and in the controller function I check the value of the form in the database and after that I display another confirmation box before executing the action depends of the value of the form.

My question is how to display the 2nd confirmation box in my exemple

This is my view:

```
<div>
    <form id="regexpForm" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test" />
        <ul>
            <li class="clear mandatory">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation"></div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        var userConfirmed = false;
        $("#regexpForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    open: function () {
                        var markup = 'Confirmation';
                        $(this).html(markup);
                    },
                     buttons: {
                         "Ok": function() {
                             form.submit();
                             $(this).dialog("close");
                         },
                         "Cancel": function() {
                             $(this).dialog("close");
                         }
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the function in my controller:

```
public function testAction()
{
    //Verification of $this->get('request')->get('action') in DB
    if($this->get('request')->get('action'))
    {
        // Display a confirmation box and if ok execute action 1
    }
    else
    {
        // Display a confirmation box and if ok execute action 2
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don`t understand why the user should confirm twice. if you need to change the form depending on certain things, you could see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Comment: The 1st confirmation is for the format of data in input (using regex) and the 2nd is after checking in the database

Comment: Just a comment: if you have the power of Symfony on your back, you should use the form component rather than writing forms by hand

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an ajax call to your `testAction`. If the expected value is ok, you return a flag that says so. Then you catch this flag in your javascript. If the flag is `true` you display another confirmation box.
Then, when the user will validate that second confirmation box, you will make another call to whatever `action` in your `controller` you want, that will execute action 1 or 2.
The point is, this is a two step process.